# What does it mean "to rock a coat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

What does it mean "to rock a coat"? Does it mean to wear it?

> Still rocking my J Crew navy peacoat. Thing is warm as f-k.
>
> Zara-man coat I bought in Copenhagen in 2008. Still rocking it, still holding up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The most up-voted, relevant definition of "rock" on Urban Dictionary](http://rock.urbanup.com/6109) is: "to use. to make do with. usually to great effect. [sic]"

I've always understood "rock," in this usage, to be related to "rock and roll." To use/wear/do something with a bit of attitude, spunk, etc. For example: "dude, I would totally rock that jean jacket."